# subtract two cell arrays then add the distance to new cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, cells

I have two cell arrays, i would like to get the absolute differnce between two cells ,then add cells to new cell array, for example:

```
A={1.1 2.1 ; 1.2 3.2};
B={1 2};
```

Perform Aggregation Function as follow:

```
d(1) =|1.1 - 1|+|2.1-2| =0.2 and d(2)=1.4
```

Then the result should be updated cell array:

```
A_Updated={1.1 2.1 d1; 1.2 3.2  d2};
```

I used the fowllowing code to subtract two cells:

```
C = cellfun((@minus),A,B,'UniformOutput',false);
C=num2cell(abs(cell2mat(C)));
```

how to add them and update cell array with new distance?

Comment: Why do you work with cell arrays? Work with numerical matrices instead.

Comment: cause my cell array contains other strings ,but i seperated it ,i convert it to matrix then to cell , it's not my problem now.

Comment: @azzaali Why did you convert it to a matrix and then a cell. Do the math after you convert it to a matrix and then convert back to a cell if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will find the distance and update as required.When size of `A` is mx2 and size of `B` is 1x2.

```
A={1.1 2.1 ; 1.2 3.2};
B={1 2};

for i=1:size(A,1)
    d1{i,1}=abs(A{i,1}- B{1})+abs(A{i,2}- B{2});
end

A_Updated=[A d1];
```

**Update:** When size of `A` is mx2 and size of `B` is kx2

```
A={1.1 2.1 ; 1.2 3.2};
B={1 2;2 1};


for i=1:size(A,1)
    for j=1:size(B,1)
    d1{i,j}=abs(A{i,1}- B{j,1})+abs(A{i,2}- B{j,2});
    end
end

A_Updated=[A d1];
```

**Update:** When size of `A` is mxn and size of `B` is kxn

```
A={1.1 2.1 ; 1.2 3.2};
B={1 2;2 1};


for i=1:size(A,1)
    for j=1:size(B,1)
        d1{i,j}=0;
        for k=1:size(B,2)
            d1{i,j}=d1{i,j}+abs(A{i,k}- B{j,k});
        end
    end
end

A_Updated=[A d1];
```

Comment: Thanks it works correctly, but what about if (B) size and (A) size is  (n*m) cell ,it will be neasted loop ?

Comment: Yes it may be. Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: my cells size not fixed i have (m*n) cells for (A) and (B) .how to do that ?

Comment: This wont work with `d(1) =|1.1 - 1|+|2.1-2| =0.2 and d(2)=1.4`. You have to provide more info. You cant just go on and change the size of one array.

Comment: Tell me how `A_Updated` will look like after making size of A and B same.

Comment: `A_Updated` will be (m*n) where m=number of rows of (A) **size(A,1)** and n =number of coulmns size(A,2) + size(B,1) , where size(B,1) will be new columns of distance

Comment: Okay ,that's exactly what i need , but When size of **A is mxn** and size of **B is k x w** .

Comment: Put it in another nested loop. But `n` must be equal to `w`. If its not you cant do it with `d(1) =|1.1 - 1|+|2.1-2| =0.2 and d(2)=1.4`. How are you going to subtract if the column count is different?

Comment: Thanks for your great answer ,that's exactly what i need